# Do I need a constant internet connection for Pokémon Go?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Is internet required to start and play Pokémon Go?

I do not have a big data plan (500Mb), and prefer to avoid blowing it on games. I have Wi-Fi at home, but Pokémon Go is not played at home.

Is it possible to login at home, go on a walk without internet to play and capture, then get back home to validate the progress?

I am fine with not participating in the multiplayer parts like battling other player, as long as I can hunt for Pokémon.

Comment: I heard the amount of data it uses is slim, havent checked how much I used so far though.

Comment: @Gigala: It s not so much about the quantity, I have realy hard restriction on data, and even "slim" use here and there accumulate a lot. Especially when you add all the unblockable network things Android do in the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the game needs an active internet connection to grab new data depending on your location.

The only way it could work like you suggested is if the game would cache the entire map (inclusive of pokémon locations and encounter triggers) and handle this entirely client side. The game is highly likely not to work this way, as the predecessor that this game was based off of didn't either (Ingress). In addition, something like that would make the game easier to cheat as the servers would have to completely trust the client.

Edit:
An idea I had for your specific case is that you might be able to find apps (or maybe features supported within your mobile OS) that allow you to cherry pick which apps can and cannot use carrier data. This would allow you to only grant Pokemon GO permission to consume data, but be sure to keep an eye on how much it is using.

Edit2:
I've been playing Pokemon GO for about 3 hours outside now, according to my Android OS it has used about ~5MB (MegaBYTE, not bit) of data. Depending on your own play style, your mileage may vary of course.

Comment: Their are way to verify if the pokemon captured was really the one meant to be server side by comparing type, date and location of capture with the one expected, it was a shot in the dark.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I've added a possible solution for your specific case.

Comment: While it is more a workaround than a pure solution, it is for now the better I can hope. I ll just wait for someone else to answer / give some number, and I ll accept something :)

Comment: @DrakaSAN I've added my own rate of data consumption, hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, Accepted :) Just sad for me I ll have to use data.